# how do x, y, z, and h gates transform amplitude, phase, and magnitude? Affect of one gate to others?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate

I have been taking the qiskit and I am having trouble understanding how they work.
How does the phase affect the actually probability of the output?
The course also talks about the amplitude trees of the x, y, z, and h gates.
After reading the course, I have no idea how the x, y, z, and h gates actually affect the parts of gate (amplitude, phase, and magnitude).
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a link to the section you're mentioning in your question ?

Comment: These may help: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate